# React Styled component: how to add css styles based on props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to find the solution to my problem.
I have several Heading Tags (H1, H2 etc) each in their own file.
I would like to add some css when calling them based on a prop. Some headings have a small border-bottom and some don't. So, in order to refractor my code, I want to add some css based on a prop. I can't seem to find a way.

Here's an example of Heading H2:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import colors from '../../../../colors'; 
import fonts from '../../../../fonts';
import fontWeights from '../../../../fontWeights';

const HeadingH2 = styled.h2`
  color: ${colors.text};
  font-family: ${fonts.montSerrat};
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-weight: ${fontWeights.light};
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  padding-bottom: 0.7em;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  &:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    width: 45px;
    background-color: currentColor;
    /* position */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
`;

export default HeadingH2
```

Example of calling Heading H2:

```
import React from 'react';
import HeadingH2 from '../../common/headings/heading_h2';
import HeadingBaseline from '../../common/headings_baseline';


// Features
import {SectionContainer, FeaturesContainer} from './features.style';

import Feature from './feature';
import feature1 from '../../../img/features/feature1.png';
import feature2 from '../../../img/features/feature2.png';
import feature3 from '../../../img/features/feature3.png';

// Text
import Text from '../../../content';

const Features = () => {
  return(
    <SectionContainer id={"what"}>
      <HeadingH2>
        What We Do
      </HeadingH2>
    <HeadingBaseline>
      {Text.headingBaseline}
    </HeadingBaseline>
  <FeaturesContainer>
    <Feature 
      src={feature1} 
      headingText={Text.feature1.heading}
      paragraph={Text.feature1.paragraph}
      />
    <Feature 
      src={feature2} 
      headingText={Text.feature2.heading}
      paragraph={Text.feature2.paragraph}
      />
    <Feature 
      src={feature3} 
      headingText={Text.feature3.heading}
      paragraph={Text.feature3.paragraph}
      />
  </FeaturesContainer>
</SectionContainer>
)
};

export default Features;
```

I want to extract the following CSS properties

```
position: relative;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
&:after{
 content: "";
 display: block;
 height: 3px;
 width: 45px;
 background-color: currentColor;
 /* position */
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
```

So, assuming I have the above CSS rule in a separate file, how do I add/import them using props on my styled component HeadingH2.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I've never used styled-components but there appears to be an example of what you want to do [on the library's homepage](https://www.styled-components.com/).  Essentially the styled component has access to props when building the CSS string and you could overwrite/add styles based on them.

Comment: not quite. I need to be able to add css rules whenever I want and from a specific file. The example on the homapage is not modular at all.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this works:

```
const HeadingH2 = styled.h2`
  position: ${props => props.relative && 'relative'};
  padding: ${props => props.paddingBottom ? '0 0 20px 0' : '0'};
}
`;
```

Then use like this:

```
<HeadingH2 relative paddingBottom />
```

Comment: I need to find a way to call those css properties from a separate file or something to reduce code repetitions

Comment: This is the best answer for using props with `styled-components`

Comment: @allan00958 you can import the styled component.  You can change the properties using React Props when you consume the component.

Comment: @allan00958 Please mark this answer as correct if it worked for you :) Thanks!

Comment: @jsw324 No, this answer doesn't work for me at all. I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `css` helper from `styled-components` to create a `SharedStyles.js` file.

In the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wojzp2x1ll) you can see it in action.
Just using it in a style of an inherited component is not working as expected. If I'm adding it to `StyledBase` then the variables are not correctly added afterwards (hover style override stops working).
That's why I copied `${borderBottom}` to each styled component `Heading1` / `Heading2` instead of adding it to `StyledBase`.

I think having a level prop for the heading is a good idea but I would handle it differently by creating a `HeadingBase` component and add your styles to a `StyledBase` component (also see code in the demo).

The `HeadingBase` code looks like this:

```
const HeadingBase = ({ className, children, level = 1 }) =>
    React.createElement(`h${level}`, { className }, children);
```

It's a component that renders h1,h2,... tags based on the prop `level` passed (defaults to h1). The h-tag receives `className` as props (needed for styled-components) and contains the children passed to the component.

**SharedStyles.js**

```
import { css } from "styled-components";

export const borderBottom = css`
    &:after{
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 3px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: ${props => props.color || "black"};
        /* position */
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
`;
```

Then you can import it with `import { borderBottom } from "./SharedStyles";` and add it to your styled-component like following:

```
const Heading1= styled.h1`
    ${borderBottom}
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer:

I add the following CSS rules in a separate file like so.
I create a function which returns a string of text. I can import this function and add those rules to any component I wish.

```
export const borderBottom = () => {
  return `
   position: relative;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   text-align: center;
   &:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    width: 45px;
    background-color: currentColor;
    /* position */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  } 
`
 }
```

And use it like so on any heading or component that I wish:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import colors from '../../../../colors';
import fonts from '../../../../fonts';
import fontWeights from  '../../../../fontWeights';
import {borderBottom} from '../../../../css';

const HeadingH5 = styled.h5`
  color: ${colors.black};
  font-family: ${fonts.montSerrat};
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: ${fontWeights.light};
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.45em;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  ${borderBottom}
`  
;

export default HeadingH5;
```

This works for me. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Could you please explain what is the solution? It's nice that you provided an answer to your own question, but if you want others to benefit from it you should explain what you did to fix the problem and why. If you posted this as a continuation of your own problem, please update the question instead.

Comment: I create a function that returns some CSS properties/values as string and import/export them using string substitution into any styled component that I wish. That way my code is dry and modular.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a `headingLevel` prop? and then pass it into the styled component? And just have one `StyledHeader` styled component as I'm guessing the code is the mostly the same in all the heading styles files? Which is a big no no, you want to always try not to repeat your code.

```
const Features = () => {
  return(
    <SectionContainer id={"what"}>
      <StyledHeader
        headingLevel={headingLevel}
      >
        What We Do
      </StyledHeader>
    <HeadingBaseline>
      {Text.headingBaseline}
    </HeadingBaseline>
  <FeaturesContainer>
    <Feature 
      src={feature1} 
      headingText={Text.feature1.heading}
      paragraph={Text.feature1.paragraph}
      />
    <Feature 
      src={feature2} 
      headingText={Text.feature2.heading}
      paragraph={Text.feature2.paragraph}
      />
    <Feature 
      src={feature3} 
      headingText={Text.feature3.heading}
      paragraph={Text.feature3.paragraph}
      />
  </FeaturesContainer>
</SectionContainer>
)
};

export default Features;
```

And in your `StyledHeader` file

The below function will take your passed in heading level of `h1`, `h2`, `h3` and will apply a border, if not the above 3 heading level it will be 0 value. I'd do some checks to ensure the value is lower case e.g. toLowerCase()

```
const getBorder = ({ headingLevel } ) => {
  const headingLevelMap = {
    h1: 0.7,
    h2: 0.6,
    h3: 0.6,
  };

  return headingLevelMap[headingLevel] || 0;
}

const HeadingH2 = styled.headingLevel`
  color: ${colors.text};
  font-family: ${fonts.montSerrat};
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-weight: ${fontWeights.light};
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  padding-bottom: 0.7em;
  border-bottom: ${getCorrectBorderBottom}em solid black
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  &:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    width: 45px;
    background-color: currentColor;
    /* position */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
`;
```

I'd also check that if the value of the passed in `headingLevel` is not any of the 6 heading levels it should have a default value of whatever you want.

The above was just quick pseudo code, but hopefully get the general idea here? Let me know it comments if not.

I'd also recommend that you split your `Title` component out into a separate component.

Comment: I sort of get it but I think it's not the right solution. I found something that works using concatenation. I will update my original question.

Comment: I posted my solution

Answer (score 0):

You should definely check this: [typestyle](https://typestyle.github.io/#/)

the best way you can write dynamic css (for me). Works perfectly with react, even with ssr if you need it...