# How to implement D.R.Y. on a duplicated header element in Styled Components?

Tags: header, styled-components, dry

Not a fan of duplicating code I've been researching for a way to build a component that I can pass header elements and then call upon it in my site (somewhat of a site default I guess you could say). In my theme folder I've created my *index.js* with set colors, sizes, etc. etc and created a *GlobalStyles.js* with my components, for example:

```js
export const H1 = styled.h1`
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.color03};
  font-size: ${({ theme }) => theme.desktopSizes.h1};
  @media only screen and (max-width: ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints.md}) {
    font-size: ${({ theme }) => theme.mobileSizes.h1};
  }
`

export const H2 = styled.h2`
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.color03};
  font-size: ${({ theme }) => theme.desktopSizes.h2};
  @media only screen and (max-width: ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints.md}) {
    font-size: ${({ theme }) => theme.mobileSizes.h2};
  }
`
```

and this goes on all the way to the `h5` element. Usage would be in `src` calling upon it with a typical:

```js
// Master Styled Components
import { H1, H2 } from '../../theme/GlobalStyles'
```

usage:

```js
<H1>Header 1</H1>
<H2>Header 2</H2>
```

and if I wanted to modify or add to it I'm aware of:

```js
const H1 = styled(H1)`
 // code
`
```

when I tried to write this out I realized that if I wanted to pass it to a main `Header` component that, from my research in the docs, the element would need to be passed, example:

```
const Header = styled.element`
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.color03};
`
```

then I was going to do:

```js
export const H1 = styled(Header)`
  font-size: ${({ theme }) => theme.desktopSizes.h1};
  @media only screen and (max-width: ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints.md}) {
    font-size: ${({ theme }) => theme.mobileSizes.h1};
  }
`
```

but dont think that would work from my research and other areas of searching I've read:

- [DRY-ing up styled-components](https://css-tricks.com/dry-ing-up-styled-components/)
- [Styled-Components ultimate props](https://medium.com/@yairevenor/styled-components-ultimate-props-local-theme-global-theme-combined-21f4d57c2e2b)
- [Advanced Usage](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced)
- [Styled components, two layers of className - How would I apply style in component declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63854845/styled-components-two-layers-of-classname-how-would-i-apply-style-in-componen)
- [React Styled component: how to add css styles based on props?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53988374/react-styled-component-how-to-add-css-styles-based-on-props)
- [DRY with Props in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61530277/dry-with-props-in-react)
- [idiomatic way to share styles in styled-components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618997/idiomatic-way-to-share-styles-in-styled-components)

In Styled Components is there a way to implement D.R.Y. when building a header component that only has a changing theme size?